# Multiline PS1 prompt

Tags: prompt, ksh

Is the a way to specify a multi line prompt in Korn shell?

I am planning to swhitch from bash to ksh. In bash I have a very simplistic prompt, but it is 2 line prompt. I hate when input position changes depending on directory depth. My PS1 in bash is:

```
PS1='$(echo $?): \w\n>> '
```

Which results in prompt like:

```
0: /var/log
>> _
```

Answer (score 13):

Just put an embedded newline inside the string:

```sh
PS1='$(echo $?): $PWD
>> '
```

Comment: Such a trivial thing! I tried putting newline char and it did not work. Did not think about explicitly putting newline.

Comment: May I suggest you change the `>>` to something else? '`>` or `>>` in a prompt may lead to nasty results if you accidentally cut&paste your screen contents. Maybe `»` or with an UTF-8 charset `►` is also a nice prompt and has no special meaning for a shell.

Comment: `$'\n'` will embed a newline too.

Comment: @amphetamachine, not in my Ksh. Where you tried that?

Comment: I think `$'string'` is `bash` only which wouldn't help here.  The embedded newline approach is probably the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me on ksh

```
PS1=$'$HOSTNAME $PWD\n$ '
```

The output is like below

```
myhost /user/varghese
$
```